# Django: Create a Foreign Key on an already populated table

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two tables that have already been populated(~1700 entries each):

```
class Drug(models.Model):
    drug_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_generic = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    indication = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    approval_company = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    research = NullBooleanField()
    successor = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    founded = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have it set up so that approval_company in Drug is a match to name in Company. What I would like to do is to make the approval_company field on Drug that has a Foreign Key relationship to Company.
After setting
`approval_company = models.ForeignKey(Company)`, and then adding the constraint in postgres, I get a ProgrammingError whenever I try to visit the django admin page for Drug.
Django tries to look for an `approval_company_id` field that does not exist. How would I go about adding this Foreign Key relationship on a table that already has many values?

Comment: You should be using django's migrations for doing this, and you should not be doing the SQL updates yourself.. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#workflow

Comment: If you really have to hack it, create the field in your DB, create the the FK manually and run fake migration by doing `manage.py migrate --fake`